# react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:97 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Check the render method of `Category`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at FoodCard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:966:5)
    at Category (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2829:66)
```

My error might be generated from this snippet of code but I am not sure.

```
const Category = () =>{
    
    const {category} = useParams();
    const {categoriesMap} = useContext(CategoriesContext);
    const[products, setProducts] = useState([categoriesMap[category]]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setProducts(categoriesMap[category]);
    }, [category, categoriesMap])

     return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2 className='category-title'>{category.toUpperCase()}</h2>
      <div className='category-container'>
        {products &&
          products
          .map((food) => (
            <FoodCard key={food.id} food={food} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

Comment: Checkout if `food.id` is `undefined` for any of the item

Answer (score 0):

your issue seems to come from `key={food.id}`

you should check out your `food.id` values. There is probably two identical value in your dataset

Comment: I checked the dataset and there aren't any duplicate id values